# How do you iterate a second request using information from first request in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, nested, httprequest

How do you send a second http request which contains requirements from the first request eg:

1. First http request sent to a website
2. Scraped a href URL
3. Send second request using the href URL we scraped

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do second request in callback function of first request .